# Как написать свою кнопку

Tags: c#, winforms, design

Подскажите как нарисовать точную кнопку взял из сайта: [Ссылка на кнопку](https://whatpulse.org/?os=macos)

В самом низу есть кнопка с надписью **"Blog Archive"**, как сделать такую же анимацию и освещение кнопки при клике?!

**Правка!**

Приложение WinForms

Собственно как она выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поправил ссылку)

Comment: WinForms,WPF или что? Для чего кнопка?

Comment: Никакой кнопки внизу нет. Смотрел, выключив NoScript. Требуется залогиниться?

Comment: А можете просто загрузить как картинку из ссылки со стороннего сайта?

Comment: Ещё вопрос: что вы исследовали, что пытались сделать?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov,я просто хочу понять как начать рисовать похоже

Comment: Можно просто менять фоновые картинки на панели по событиям `MouseEnter` и `MouseLeave`. Можно более интересно, на базе `UserControl`, и весь код упаковать внутрь контрола. Зависит от ваших знаний и умений, мне больше второй вариант нравится, но для прототипа подойдет и первый.

Answer (score 0):

Как написать свою кнопку? - "написать" можно в xamle. Но для этого нужно перейти на WPF.

Как начать рисовать похоже? - Нарисовать вы можете что угодно, и использовать пустую кнопку с нарисованным изображением, привязав изменения к событиям (нажатия например)